# How to allocate an ipv6 address to a secondary interface on a router

Tags: routes, ipv6

I am writing code to make an IPv6 router.
My router has one primary interface, that connects to a WiFi router, and gets its ip address from the router. The second interface uses a different transport technology, but does not have a global IP address.
Devices connecting to the router over the second interface must derive their IPv6 addresses from the Prefix provided by my router over the second interface. 
I am not sure how to get a global prefix for the second interface, which will make it possible to send datagrams to devices on that subnet from outside of the WiFi router. I would appreciate some pointers on how to get a suitable global prefix. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming?

Comment: You would need an upstream router that provides DHCPv6 prefix delegation (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3633), or better even: homenet (https://tools.ietf.org/wg/homenet/charters).

Comment: Thank you, Sander. It looks just like what I need.

Comment: Ron, I was not sure about the starting point for a solution, which is why I asked. However, I do apologize if my query was inappropriate.